# Connector NoSuchMethodError with complex query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

NoSuchMethodErrorUsing the Simba connector, the following query gives me the error below. The query worked fine in the web console tool thingie. All the jar files seem to be there. I updated the JDBC driver version to the latest and get the same error. I turned on logging and it looks like it's about ready to return the results to me before it crashes.

```
SELECT *field list* FROM *table* bu LEFT OUTER JOIN *table* a on bu.field1
 = a.field1 AND bu.field2 = a.field2 LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT field1, *field list* FROM *table*) AS av on bu.field1 = CAST(av.field1 AS string) WHERE a.field3="Physical";
```

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.apache.avro.LogicalType org.apache.avro.Schema.getLogicalType()'
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroStructToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroArrayToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroStructToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTParser.avroToString(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQHTDataHandler.retrieveData(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.dataengine.BQResultSet.getData(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.getData(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.SForwardResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    at com.service_now.monitor.jdbc.JDBCRowSet.next(JDBCRowSet.java:186)
    at com.service_now.monitor.jdbc.JDBCMultiRowSet.next(JDBCMultiRowSet.java:19)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.doSelect(JDBCProbe.java:335)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.doQuery(JDBCProbe.java:199)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.JDBCProbe.probe(JDBCProbe.java:126)
    at com.service_now.mid.probe.AProbe.process(AProbe.java:102)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorker.runWorker(AWorker.java:122)
    at com.service_now.mid.queue_worker.AWorkerThread.run(AWorkerThread.java:20)
    at com.service_now.mid.threadpool.ResourceUserQueue$RunnableProxy.run(ResourceUserQueue.java:649)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: If it helps, I believe we're using SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.21.1025

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like the issue was caused byt the fact that I didn't have a limit or provide LargeResultDataset and LargeResultTable parameters. I hope someone finds this useful since this is a very misleading error that nobody has documented.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).